# Какова причина постановки тире?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, тире-или-двоеточие

**Вдали вилась пыль — Азамат скакал на лихом Карагезе;** (М. Лермонтов).

В этом случае второе предложение обозначает **причину** первого, поэтому по классическим правилам нужно ставить двоеточие. **Почему автор поставил тире?**

На каких принципах пунктуации (семантическом, грамматическом, интонационном) основан выбор двоеточия или тире в данном предложении?

Comment: Ну вы же знаете, вместо двоеточия в этом случае допускается и тире.

Comment: Конечно, я знаю, что допускается, меня интересует, как сделан выбор. Есть ли разница в грамматике, семантике и интонации? Мне хочется понять, что дает нам именно конкретный знак. Или  это простая УСЛОВНОСТЬ, или что? Может быть,  графика лучше смотрится? И зачем тогда вообще  изучать десятки правил на тему постановки двоеточия и тире, если они свободно заменяют друг друга? Надо тогда отменить все эти правила и четко сформулировать только те, где замена невозможна. Нельзя же писать законы и тут же говорить, что соблюдать их необязательно.  Разве мало на форуме вопросов на эту тему?

Comment: Двоеточие просто указывает на причину. А поскольку тире эмоциональный знак, на мой взгляд, дополнительно указывает на выразительность, экспрессию. Впрочем, трудно сказать, какая пунктуация была в оригинале.

Answer (score 1):

Вот что пишет Д. Э. Розенталь по этому поводу.

«...в «конкурентной борьбе» **двоеточия с тире «победителем» нередко выходит тире.** Это явление отмечается многими исследователями, которые считают, что «в целом тире — знак более свободный, заходящий и во владения двоеточия»[36] и что «выявляется тенденция к вытеснению в ряде случаев двоеточия знаком тире». Объяснить это можно **особым статусом тире среди других знаков препинания: «В настоящее время тире очень употребительный и многофункциональный знак препинания. Он выполняет как грамматические (чисто синтаксические), так и эмоционально-экспрессивные функции; особенно широко используется он в последнем качестве в художественной литературе»**.

Наблюдения над современной периодической печатью подтверждают вывод об «агрессивности» тире: **За годы, прошедшие со времени подписания Заключительного акта в Хельсинки, миллионы людей, прежде всего в Европе, лично сумели оценить всё то доброе, что дала им разрядка, — преимущества мирной спокойной жизни, экономического, научно-технического и культурного сотрудничества (Газ.); Выборы позади — можно отдохнуть (Газ.)».**

Comment: Спасибо, Серж, за ответ. Итак, Розенталь считает тире свободным и многофункциональным знаком. Оно выполняет не только синтаксические, но и эмоционально-экспрессивные функции. А как это приложить к данному предложению? Тире расширяет свои полномочия, обозначая любые причинно-следственные отношения  (причина - следствие и следствие - причина). Да, автор решил их обозначить обобщенно, но все равно остается вопрос: почему он решил именно так? И в чем заключается эта эмоционально-экспрессивная ф-ия, если она здесь есть. Как увидеть конкретику за общими словами - вот бы что спросить у Розенталя.

Answer (score 1):

Так четко и терминологически грамотно (как специалисты) я сказать не смогу, поэтому приведу мнение [**Грамоты.ру**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=202351).

**Вопрос** № 202351.
Будет ли ошибкой, если вместо двоеточия поставить тире (…)?

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

Вот что пишет Н. С. Валгина в книге «Активные процессы в современном русском языке».

Выявляется тенденция к вытеснению двоеточия знаком тире в тех случаях, когда **пояснительно-разъяснительный смысл конструкций очевиден — смысловые отношения частей предложения проявляются на лексическом уровне, лежат на поверхности.**

Употребление двоеточия сводится к очень конкретным и явно немногочисленным конструкциям, особенно закрепляется оно в позиции перед перечислением (хотя и здесь тире уже достаточно потеснило двоеточие).
В других же случаях, даже когда оно поддерживается ныне действующими правилами пунктуации, двоеточие практически заменяется тире. <...>

Практика такого широкого употребления тире вместо двоеточия (а иногда и запятой) отнюдь не свидетельствует о том, что в тех же условиях уже не может стоять обычный знак: параллельное употребление свидетельствует лишь о наметившейся тенденции и, следовательно, в данное время о возможности выбора знака — более традиционного, строгого, "академического" (двоеточия) и нового, **более вольного, энергичного и экспрессивного** (тире). **Выбор зависит от характера текста, манеры изложения, наконец, авторской привычки**, но ясно одно — сдержать наступательное движение тире уже нельзя.
. . . . . . . . .

**В небольшой комнатке пыль стояла столбом — долбили молотками сразу несколько человек** (А. Белов).
Перед глазами возникают два действа — витающая пыль и грохочущие молотки, каждое по отдельности, — и разделить их на причину-следствие практически невозможно. Мне кажется, что вторую часть предложения можно даже заключить в скобки — как вставку.
Точно так же я "вижу" и лермонтовское предложение.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. В принципе впечатление такое же: да, тире наступает, вытесняет, знак экспрессивный, энергичный, автор может позволить себе выбор. А школьник, который выучил все правила, он что себе может позволить? Ведь конкретики нет никакой. Вот в вашем примере вполне ясно, где причина и где следствие, просто автор не счет нужным это обозначать. Ему важно было показать взаимосвязь, взаимообусловленность, и с этой задачей.прекрасно справилось тире.

Comment: @  Jasmin, школьник может обойтись и двоеточием.

Comment: >> Вот что пишет Н. С. Валгина в книге «Активные процессы в современном русском языке»...

@ Римма Михайлова, но фраза написана почти 200 лет назад.

Comment: _Своё_ вИдение я изложила в конце ответа. Наличие двоеточия в предложении часто предполагает: готовьтесь, я сейчас перечислять или объяснять буду! Автор _намеренно_ избегает такого восприятия. Ему важны *оба* действия - и витие пыли, и всадник на лихом коне - как единое целое.

Answer (score 1):

**Вдали вилась пыль — Азамат скакал на лихом Карагезе.**

Что мне показалось важным из ответов? Это, пожалуй, то, что замену двоеточия тире   **можно обосновать, используя хотя бы какие-то официальные источники.**

Двоеточие  — это знак, который **часто содержит избыточную информацию**. Он точно указывает на причину и следствие, но часто это и так ясно из семантики текста. К тому же двоеточие требует предупредительной паузы при чтении.

А для современного языка особенно важна **сжатость, информативная насыщенность текста, важен энергичный темп речи,** его яркость, искрометность и пр. Всё это не сочетается с медлительным и "многословным" двоеточием.

Поэтому ответ такой. **Автор может использовать тире вместо двоеточия,** если он хочет обозначить причинно-следственные отношения между предложениями, не указывая конкретно, где следствие,  а где причина.